# D2R auto map discovering algorithm

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, bots

I'm trying (for technical challenge) to create an autonomous bot able to play D2R alone.

Of course, it would be an offline bot, just used for my personnal satisfaction ;)

I manage to overcome most of my first technical challenges :

- Screen detection / Menu and game creation handling (screen patterns)
- Monster detection : Deep learning based algorithm is working really fine (even without GPU training, first attempts are great !)
- Item and fixed spots detection : Handled by screen pattern recognition

But there is another issue that I don't managed to get rid off :
how to manage the movement of my character ? A* and so on won't be working because in D2R there are no nodes and links or anything like that. And moreover We don't know before discovering the maps where is the output of the map.

Checking the minimap i can get with pattern recognition the entrance/output of a level but I don't see how I could handle the movements !

Here some example of screen in this one the entrance is in pink on minimap, but we cannot see the output of this level, it has to been discovered:
[image]

And this one is already full discovered:
[image]

I would like my bot to be a pixel bot and using only screen information. I don't want to inject into memory of anything like this (if possible).

Anyone with an idea of algorithm or technicals possibilities how I could make that?

I thought of map reconstruction while discovering it but how to get walls information (another deep learning model ? seems not the best, perhaps trying to isolate the minimap information?)

Thanks really all for your ideas and help !

P.S. : Working with python, OpenCV and imageai

Comment: a concrete example (picture) would benefit your question. the picture that's there doesn't illustrate the problem.

Comment: I know but it's difficult to find an image to explain what i want to do, i'll update with some images